# Using SqlDataAdapter to insert a row

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to insert a row into the Database using SqlDataAdapter. I've 2 tables (Custormers & Orders) in CustomerOrders database and has more than thousand records. I want to create a GUI (TextBoxes) for adding new customer & orders into the Database to their respective tables.

- How should I do it?

I guess the method that is usually followed is

```
dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter (sqlQuery, conn);
dataSet = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dataSet);
```

Now take the values from textboxes (or use DataBinding) to add a new row into the dataSet and call

```
  da.Update(dataSet);
```

But the Question is Why should I fetch all other records into dataSet using da.Fill(dataSet ) in the first place? I just want to add a single new record.

For this purpose what I'm doing is, Creating the schema of the Database in the DataSet. like this:

```
  DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet("CustomerOrders");

  DataTable customers = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Customers");
  DataTable orders = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Orders");

  customers.Columns.Add("CustomerID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
  customers.Columns.Add("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
  customers.Columns.Add("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
  customers.Columns.Add("Phone", Type.GetType("System.String"));
  customers.Columns.Add("Email", Type.GetType("System.String"));

  orders.Columns.Add("CustomerID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
  orders.Columns.Add("OrderID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
  orders.Columns.Add("OrderAmount", Type.GetType("System.Double"));
  orders.Columns.Add("OrderDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

  customerOrders.Relations.Add("Cust_Order_Rel", customerOrders.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"], customerOrders.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
```

I used DataBinding to bind these columns to respective text boxes.
Now I'm confused! What should I do next? How to use Insert command? Because I didn't give any dataAdapter.SelectCommand so dataAdapter.Update() wont work I guess. Please suggest a correct approach.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Set the select command with a "0 = 1" filter and use an [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) so that the insert command is automatically generated for you.

```
var sqlQuery = "select * from Customers where 0 = 1";
dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

var newRow = dataSet.Tables["Customers"].NewRow();
newRow["CustomerID"] = 55;
dataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Add(newRow);

new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Comment: That "WHERE 0 = 1" was a lifesaver. (Loading a media table of 2GB into memory...sigh..)

Comment: I was interested in the line `new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);` - that makes some magic happen so I don't have to script the whole of the INSERT statements. Thanks!

Comment: dataSet.Tables["Customers"].Add(newRow); doesn't compile. "System.Data.DataTable does not contain a definition for 'Add'". Do you mean dataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(newRow);?

Comment: WHERE 0=1? I think more elegant is  'SELECT TOP(0)...'

Comment: @fcm Both queries should have identical execution plans, but WHERE 1 = 0 has the advantage of being ANSI SQL compliant, while the TOP keyword is vendor-specific. Any RDBMS that understands any version of SQL will understand WHERE 1 = 0. It's a pattern used quite extensively in code-generated SQL queries, too.

Answer (score 7):

You can fill the `dataSet` with an empty set e.g.:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter ("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE id = -1", conn);
dataSet = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dataSet);
```

Then you add your rows and call update.

For this scenario though it would probably be better not to use `SqlDataAdapter`. Instead use the `SqlCommand` object directly for insertion. (Even better, use LINQ to SQL or any other ORM)

Comment: I thought of it. But I've a form conatining more than 200 Text Columns. So, I opted this.

Comment: @Manu this will not work if the Id uses  negative values - you might get 1 row returned. Nathans answers assures 0 rows returned. However it still makes a db trip.

Answer (score -6):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter("Insert Into Employee values("+textBox1.Text+",'"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"',"+textBox4.Text+")",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

I have to do first time. You can try it . It works well.

Comment: this may work but at least I find databinding is clearer and less vulnerable to error for large number of input textboxes and more sturdy against table changes in the database