# SqlDataAdapter with Output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I was working with `SqlDataAdapter` which is doing insert operation and should show identity column as output parameter in application.

Here is my code

```
// created connection object
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("GetPersons",con);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

da.InsertCommand  = new SqlCommand("IPersons",con);
da.InsertCommand .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.InsertCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);

// output param
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ID";
param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

string var = da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString();
```

..but in the last line I can't get value of the output parameter, it shows null value

This is the stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[IPersons]
     @Name varchar(255) = null,
     @ID int Out
AS
Begin
     insert into Persons values(@Name)

     select @ID = scope_Identity()
End
```

What am I missing from taking out output parameter?

Comment: You can't get the value of the output parameter after filling the Dataset because the `fill` method doesn't use the InsertCommand, it uses the SelectCommand.

Comment: You need the `ExecuteScalar` method if you want to retrieve any output parameter.

Comment: @Lourayad: Wrong. it's possible to use any execute method to get back an output parameter. this is not the problem here. neeraj: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631054/using-sqldataadapter-to-insert-a-row)