# Cannot insert value via SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am learning how to work with SQL in C#, and I got in troubles with using `SqlDataAdapter`. I have tried to use direct queries via `SqlCommand` class and everything works fine, but when I rewrote my code to use `SqlDataAdapter` I have no changes in my table. There is my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADO"]
                                                                 .ConnectionString);

connection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter daUser = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Books", connection);

SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
insert.Connection = connection;
insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books (name, author) VALUES (@name, @author);";

SqlParameterCollection pc = insert.Parameters;
pc.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "test123");
pc.Add("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "test322");
daUser.InsertCommand = insert;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
daUser.Fill(ds, "Books");
daUser.Update(ds, "Books");
```

Table `Books` was created with this SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE Books 
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    author varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Books(name, author) 
VALUES('1984', 'George Orwell'), ('Fathers and sons', 'Dostoevski')
```

Looks like I am missing something to do, that why my code have no effect on table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SqlDataAdapter to insert a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631054/using-sqldataadapter-to-insert-a-row)

Comment: If you want to use an SqlDataAdapter in this context (not the correct way to do it) then you need to add your data to the table returned by the Fill method. SqlDataAdapter.Update method looks at the data changed in that table to decide what to update/insert or delete. You don't have any change there so no INSERT is called (of course you don't need the parameters)

Answer (score 2):

`SqlDataAdapter.Update` will call its `InsertCommand` only for the rows of datatable having `RowState = DataRowState.Added`.

This rowstate is automatically assigned to the datarows being added to rows collection using `DataTable.Add` method (until next call to `AcceptChanges` method). Also you can use `DataRow.SetAdded` method to force this state assignment.

Since you're not modifying/adding anything in you datatable after you've populated it with select command, it has nothing to insert.

Change your code to something like

```
daUser.Fill(ds, "Books");

var newBook = daUser.Tables[0].NewRow();
newBook["name"] = "New Book";
newBook["author"] = "Author Name";
daUser.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newBook);

daUser.Update(ds, "Books");
```

and in this case it should be new row added to the database table.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify the previous answer, which is correct, you want to call ExecuteNonQuery() on the *command* not the dataAdapter.

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(); 
insert.Connection = connection;
insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books (name, author) VALUES (@name,
@author);";
SqlParameterCollection pc = insert.Parameters;
pc.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "test123"); 
pc.Add("@author",
SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "test322"); 
// you do not need this line if you execute the insert on the command object.
// daUser.InsertCommand = insert;

//Add this line instead:
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Joey